# how to retrieve data from dynamic table - selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm trying to retrieve data from the dynamic web table in selenium python but errors in a console as 
ERROR as "

```
values = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='table01']/tbody/tr["+row+"]/td["+col+"]").text
```

TypeError: must be str, not int

FAILED (errors=1)

```
class DynamicWebTable1(unittest.TestCase):


@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    chrome_driver_path = os.path.abspath('..')  + "\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe"

    cls.driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_path)

    cls.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    cls.driver.maximize_window()
    # navigate to the application home page
    cls.driver.get("http://qavalidation.com/demo/")

def test_get_table_data(self):
    time.sleep(10)
    columns = len(self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='table01']/tbody/tr[1]/td"))
    rows = len(self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='table01']/tbody/tr"))
    print("rows - ",rows)   # rows -  3
    print("columns - ",columns) #columns -  4

    for row in range(rows):
        for col in range(columns):
            values = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='table01']/tbody/tr["+row+"]/td["+col+"]").text
            print(" Dynamic web table index {row} ,{col} value is {values} ".format(row, col, values))

@classmethod
def tearDownClass(cls):
    # close the browser window
    cls.driver.quit()
```

Github sample code https://github.com/venkywarriors619/selenium_with_python/blob/master/Python_basics/SeleniumWebDriver_Advanced/DynamicWebTable1.py[image: dynamic we table from http://qavalidation.com/demo/]

dynamic we table from http://qavalidation.com/demo/

Comment: Try `values = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='table01']/tbody/tr[%s]/td[%s]" % (row, col)).text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

...implies that while at the mentioned line your program expects a *String* type of argument where as an *Interger* type of argumnent was passed to it.

To retrieve the data from the dynamic web table you need to change the line of code as follows :

```
for row in range(rows):
    for col in range(columns):
        values = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="table01"]/tbody/tr["'+row+'"]/td["'+col+'"]').text
```

Comment: Please, update your answer, because it results in Syntax error. The correct syntax is  +"'col'"+ . First double quote ", after ', after col, after ', after double quote ".

Answer (score 0):

You can't add string and integer :

```
>>> "1"+2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    "1"+2
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

You have to convert int to str :

```
>>> "1"+str(2)
'12'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is expecting string value but you are passing int value. It happens when we concatenate string to integer. Please change the following line in your code.

```
values = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='table01']/tbody/tr["+row+"]/td["+col+"]").text
```

to

```
values = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='table01']/tbody/tr["+str(row)+"]/td["+str(col)+"]").text
```

It may resolve your issue.